# PrimeNg multiselect, select all items by default

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

I have a multiselect item from PrimeNg. I can select them if I need, but is it possible to have them all selected by default?

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="userconfig" [(ngModel)]="selectedScopes" optionLabel="name"
    maxSelectedLabels=3 (onChange)="getCheckboxScope($event)" 
    selectedItemsLabel="{0} users selected" defaultLabel="select users..."> 
</p-multiSelect>
```

Comment: manually set the initial value of `selectedScopes` to be all at start?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to have all items selected bind all values of the options ( `userconfig` ) in the multiselect into ( `selectedScopes` ) The component autodetect the property `selectedScopes` is equal to `userconfig` values and select all items.

Example:

```
export class MyModel {

    userconfig: SelectItem[];

    selectedScopes: any[];

    constructor() {
        // Options of the multiselect
        this.userconfig = [
            {label:'New York', value:{id:1, name: 'New York', code: 'NY'}},
            {label:'Rome', value:{id:2, name: 'Rome', code: 'RM'}},
            {label:'London', value:{id:3, name: 'London', code: 'LDN'}},
            {label:'Istanbul', value:{id:4, name: 'Istanbul', code: 'IST'}}
            {label:'Paris', value:{id:5, name: 'Paris', code: 'PRS'}}
        ];
       // Select all items
       selectedScopes = [];
       userconfig.map((item) => selectedScopes.push(item.value));
    }

}
```

Comment: If anyone would want to select not all but specific ones then `filter()` would work prior to map. Etc: userconfig.filter(opt=>opt.value.id == 3 || opt.value.id==4).map(...) would only select London & Istanbul

Comment: Just FYI for anyone else coming here, your selected items should be an array of string, i.e. it is the array of selected values, _not_ the array of the SelectItem, you want selected

Answer (score 1):

Use `optionValue="id"`  and make sure to `push` the id of the object in the array.

Template

```
<p-multiSelect required  [options]="projects" [(ngModel)]="selectedProjects" name="project" defaultLabel="Project"
  optionLabel="name optionValue="id">
</p-multiSelect>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since PrimeNg's MultiSelect does not inherently come with a property to select all the options by default, you can just fill your `selectedScopes` with the values from `userconfig`. Presumably you're initializing `selectedScopes` as an empty array? If you are, then instead you could do something like this:

`selectedScopes = [value1, value2, value3]`

Where the values are coming from `userconfig`. Since you're two-way binding `selectedScopes`, whatever values are already in `selectedScopes` should reflect as a selection in your MultiSelect.

(My terminology's still a bit rusty, so if anything's unclear please let me know!)